# Python: Pickle error with SVM usage

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, pickle

I am trying to save an SVR model using pickle in python. However, on first attempt a ValueError was raised:

```
ValueError: pickle protocol must be <= 2
```

I attempted to resolve this error by explicitly passing an argument as so:

```
s = pickle.dumps(w, open('svm.p', 'wb'), protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

But I now receive a TypeError:

```
TypeError: dumps() got multiple values for keyword argument 'protocol'
```

As far as i am aware my code is fine on comparison with other examples and reading through the documentation but I am unable to resolve this error. I'd be happy with saving the model through another method as long as the saved model can be transferred across workstations. Here is the relevant code:

```
import pickle

w = svm.SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e6, gamma=0.00000008, max_iter=-1, cache_size=4096)
w.fit(X, Y)

s = pickle.dumps(w, open('svm.p', 'wb'), protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

X and Y are vectors of length 17520 and X has a list of 6 data points for every element. E.g. X[0] = [0, 1, 6239.0, 6709.375, 6462.0, 6774.75] and Y[0] = 6391.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pickle.dumps doesn't take the file argument. pickle.dump does.
The interpreter is assuming that both open('svm.p', 'wb') and protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL are being passed in as the protocol version, based on the order of parameters in the method definition.

use pickle.dump as that will write the svm.p file.

Comment: I'd like to dump to a file so that I can then transfer the file to another location (server) and run a prediction script there using the dumped file whenever required without having to train every time (takes a lot of time).

Comment: I think you want pickle.dump, not pickle.dumps.

Comment: Indeed, works fine now with pickle.dump,  I got confused by the example given on the scikit-learn page. Many Thanks!

Comment: And one more remark: use sklearns [joblib](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html) which is optimized for this!